# a minimal Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver) server requirements

Tags: server, 18.04, ubuntu-minimal, system-requirements

I want to have a minimal Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server on i.MX6ULL series CPU (528MHz) with 512MB DDR SDRAM and 4GB EMMC ROM. is it possible? which kernel version do I need to have? I want to use it as smart home gateway (which don't need high process) and want to install the latest version of NodeJS on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [Ubuntu System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) page, for an Ubuntu Server minimal installation the minium hardware requirements are:

1. 300 MHz x86 processor
2. 256 MiB of system memory (RAM)
3. 1.5 GB of disk space
4. Graphics card and monitor capable of 640x480
5. CD drive (well, I think you can install via USB instead!)

so you should be good.

As they are official requirements, without any specific kernel mentioned, I think that the default Ubuntu-shipped kernel is good enough.

That said, it's not guaranteed that *anything* will run smoothly with those specs, just that the system can be installed and run.

Comment: thank you for reply. so, are the requirements sufficient for installing the latest version of NodeJS?

Comment: @King I think NodeJS _per se_ should not pose any problem. It will depend on which applications you intend to run on top of it.