# Partitioning a large SSD (256 GB) for Ubuntu server

Tags: server, partitioning, ssd, home-directory

Building an Ubuntu server. I want to install the software on an SSD I am no longer using. It is way big (256 GB) for the operating system and not big enough for an actual server data drive.

What would be a good partition schema to maximize its use in addition to the Ubuntu server software?
Thanks,

Ken (olsonkp48)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a minimal Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver) server requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134582/a-minimal-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-bionic-beaver-server-requirements)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)